# Qt Designer; difficulty placing widgets in the right parent

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Using the Qt Designer I've made a couple of QFrames in each other, each having a horizontal layout. Their stylesheet predicates that they should have no margin nor a padding. This means that in the Qt Designers view as well as in the final result, no space is seen between the QFrames.

Using drag-and-drop I can place widgets into the window, it shows a blue line where it will be placed (in a layout). However, it's impossible to add another QFrame to a QFrame parent I can't see (and thus drop on). There is also a tree in the right panel, but dropping on the parent makes it automatically go in one of the childs...

Example, I have this setup:

```
QMainWindow
- QWidget
  - QFrame (parent)
    - QFrame (child)
    - QFrame (child)
```

Adding a new frame, whatever I try, gives me:

```
QMainWindow
- QWidget
  - QFrame (parent)
    - QFrame (child)
    - QFrame (child)
    - QFrame (new child)
```

But I really want:

```
QMainWindow
- QWidget
  - QFrame (parent)
    - QFrame (child)
    - QFrame (child)
  - QFrame (new parent)
```

Is there any feature I haven't discovered to accurately place new widgets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Object Inspector window, but you don't seem to be able to paste into a QFrame that has a locked layout.

So given your layout:

```
QMainWindow
- QWidget
  - QFrame (A)
    - QFrame (B)
    - QFrame (C)
    - QFrame (D)
```

Select QFrame D in the Object Inspector window and Cut it, right click QWidget and Break the layout (ctrl-0), then paste. Then re-apply the layout.

Comment: Changing layouts and adding frames and widgets can definitely be a pain. Breaking the layout is usually what is required depending on what you are trying to change. As a trick, sometimes I use designer to create a temp form/widget. This can act like a clipboard for cutting and pasting groups of components back and forth.

Comment: This works yes, thank you. It does undo the layout for QWidget this way, which I have to re-configure, or is that inevitable?

Answer (score 8):

One workaround I've used is to select the widget I want to be adding to, add a margin to that widget's layout, drag and drop the widget, then remove the margin again.  This way, at least I get it in the correct widget.

Comment: I had this problem with putting layouts inside each other, so the other answer didn't work.  Thanks for this!

Comment: Bah or just edit the XML. I am really disappointed by the Designer.

Answer (score 1):

In Qt Creator 4.3 I also found it hard to drag an item into a layout which has no items yet.

Easiest way to get it working is to add the `Layout` to the form. Then drag your item from the `Toolbox` onto the layout in the `Object Inspecter Window`.
Which will add the item into the `Layout`.

Unknown if this works for older for older versions of Qt Creator.